# How can I transpose my Matrix to reverse columns and rows?

Tags: c

I managed to do enter M, N, and accept its condition (0<N and M<=10), then create and apply desirable number into 2 matrices, which is called Matrix A and Matrix B, then the Matrix C is the plus of 2 Matrix A B.

The last one is the transpose, I have looked upon some sites, but since the ways they do are not like mine so I don't like to just "straightly" copy and paste it.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int M, N, i, j;

printf ("Enter number M: ");
scanf("%d", &M);
printf ("Enter number N: ");
scanf("%d", &N);

if (0 < N && M <= 10) {
    printf ("Accepted number M: %d\n", M);
    printf("Accepted number N: %d\n", N);
}
else printf("Please enter valid number, which is 0 < N and M <= 10!");

int matrixA[M][N], matrixB[M][N], matrixC[M][N];

printf ("Enter matrix A: \n");

for (i=0; i<M; i++){
   for (j=0; j<N; j++){
         scanf("%d", &matrixA[i][j]);
                        }
}

printf ("Enter matrix B: \n");

for (i=0; i<M; i++){
   for (j=0; j<N; j++){
         scanf("%d", &matrixB[i][j]);
                        }
}

printf("Matrix A: \n");
for (i=0; i<M; i++){
   for (j=0; j<N; j++){
         printf("%d ", matrixA[i][j]);
                        }
printf("\n");
}

printf("Matrix B: \n");
for (i=0; i<M; i++){
   for (j=0; j<N; j++){
         printf("%d ", matrixB[i][j]);
                        }
printf("\n");
}

for (i=0; i<M; i++){
   for (j=0; j<N; j++){
         matrixC[i][j] = matrixA[i][j] + matrixB[i][j];
                        }
}

printf("Sum of matrix A and matrix B => Matrix C is: \n");
for (i=0; i<M; i++){
   for (j=0; j<N; j++){
         printf("%d ", matrixC[i][j]);
                        }
printf("\n");
}

int reverseMatrixC[N][M];
for (i=0; i<M; i++){
   for (j=0; j<N; j++){
         reverseMatrixC[j][i] = matrixC[i][j];
                        }
}
printf("Reverse columns and rows in matrix C: \n");
for (i=0; i<M; i++){
   for (j=0; j<N; j++){
         printf("%d ", reverseMatrixC[i][j]);
                        }
printf("\n");
}
}
```

The last one "Reverse columns and rows" are wrong and I don't know why, from my way of thinking, I'm switching M and N, then apply the previous Matrix C into a new variable which is reverseMatrixC, and then reverse i and j.

For example, I choose M = 2, N = 3.
and then I choose matrixA and matrixB these value:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

The matrixC will display:

```
2 4 6
8 10 12
```

But when I transpose it, it'll display:

```
2 8 4
4 10 6
```

What I want is something like this:

```
2 8
4 10
6 12
```

Comment: <O/T> if the user enters numbers out of range, you print out an error, but then continue on with program execution as if there was no problem. You need a loop that loops back to the input prompts if validation on the input fails. Also, it's odd that you only check the lower bound for `N` and upper bound for `M`. Shouldn't you check both bounds for both values? As it stands now, `N` could be huge, `M` could be negative, and your validation will pass.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm thinking when I was at the last step, I tried to switch M and N around, too, and notice this, but I can't think of any solution right now, I'm just learned how to use Array a couple of days ago :D.

Comment: You are in danger of `N` causing a stack overflow; in this case, you need to test the lower-bounds and the upper-bounds of both `N` and `M`; that's 4 predicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close.  In fact, you're transposing `matrixC` correctly, the only problem is with how you're printing it out:

```
printf("Reverse columns and rows in matrix C: \n");
// reverseMatrixC has its rows and columns dimensions swapped, so N specifies its number of rows
for (i=0; i<N; i++){
    // and M specifies its number of columns
    for (j=0; j<M; j++){
            printf("%d ", reverseMatrixC[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Also highly recommend to fix your indentation and use an IDE that formats for you, it makes reading code much easier.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/45Gnhs1er)

Comment: Thanks for helping me, yours look so clean and beautiful, but I don't understand the part of why we have to #define M 2 and N 3 and then have to define int matrixA[M][N] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} } again. Is there anyway we can input it however we want? If don't can you explain this part for me, I just want to understand :D Thanks again :)

Comment: @MeowMeowpram Pay no attention to the `#define`s and initializer-list arrays. I did that just for me. When debugging problems like this, its easier and quicker for debugging to hardcode all your values, rather than input them every time. I'm not suggesting at all to replace the parts of your code with that for a final solution. But it is a debugging technique to be mindful of. You want to isolate problems as much as possible. The problem was with the transposition, not with the input. The hardcoding I've shown simply saves time by eliminating user input.

Comment: @MeowMeowpram For example, part of your validation (which still needs some work), accepts `M` up to 10. Assuming `N` could be the same size, that would require inputting _100_ values for a matrix. If you know that input code is working, do you really want to input 100 values each time you run to debug a problem further on in your code? I wouldn't. Instead, you can bypass that step momentarily by hardcoding the matrix in order to focus on the problem later on. Once that's fixed (and certainly before you submit your assignment!), bring back the user input.